# Can't send more than 160 bytes to module using Bluetooth on Android

Tags: bluetooth, android

I am unable to send more than 160 bytes to a Bluetooth (BLE) module from my Android application. I am sending data from my modified FastBle Android app to a microchip RN4871 Bluetooth module. I'm running BLE in transparent UART mode. After connecting to the module in the Android application and calling a notify function, I call a write function to send packets in 20-byte chunks.

However, after 160 bytes, the Android application does not send any more data; by increasing MTU, we can send up to 600 bytes, but no more.

What we basically observed is that after we modified the FastBle android code, the notify descriptor has a NULL value, which we are unable to correct because I did not understand the cause.

This is the calling code for notify and write function, the "hex" variable is the string to write.

```
  setCharaProp(2);
        ((CharacteristicOperationFragment) fragments.get(2)).showData(hex);
        setCharaProp(1);
        ((CharacteristicOperationFragment) fragments.get(2)).showData(hex);
        setCharaProp(2);
```

The code below is to notify and write:

```
 public void showData(String hex) {
      final BleDevice bleDevice = ((OperationActivity) getActivity()).getBleDevice();
      final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = ((OperationActivity) getActivity()).getCharacteristic();
      final int charaProp = ((OperationActivity) getActivity()).getCharaProp();
      String child = characteristic.getUuid().toString() + String.valueOf(charaProp);

      for (int i = 0; i < layout_container.getChildCount(); i++) {
          layout_container.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
      if (childList.contains(child)) {
          layout_container.findViewWithTag(bleDevice.getKey() + characteristic.getUuid().toString() + charaProp).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      } else {
          childList.add(child);
          View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.layout_characteric_operation, null);
          view.setTag(bleDevice.getKey() + characteristic.getUuid().toString() + charaProp);
          LinearLayout layout_add = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_add);
          final TextView txt_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
          txt_title.setText(String.valueOf(characteristic.getUuid().toString() + getActivity().getString(R.string.data_changed)));
          final TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
          txt.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());

          switch (charaProp) {
          
              case PROPERTY_WRITE:
                  {
                      View view_add = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.layout_characteric_operation_et, null);

                      if (TextUtils.isEmpty(hex)) {
                          return;
                      }
                      BleManager.getInstance().write(
                          bleDevice,
                          characteristic.getService().getUuid().toString(),
                          characteristic.getUuid().toString(),
                          HexUtil.hexStringToBytes(hex),
                          new BleWriteCallback() {

                              @Override
                              public void onWriteSuccess(final int current, final int total, final byte[] justWrite) {
                                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void run() {
                                          addText(txt, "write success, current: " + current +
                                              " total: " + total +
                                              " justWrite: " + HexUtil.formatHexString(justWrite, true));
                                      }
                                  });
                              }

                              @Override
                              public void onWriteFailure(final BleException exception) {
                                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void run() {
                                          addText(txt, exception.toString());
                                      }
                                  });
                              }
                          });
                      layout_add.addView(view_add);
                  }
                  break;
                  
              case PROPERTY_NOTIFY:
                  {
                      View view_add = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.layout_characteric_operation_button, null);
                      if (my_notify_ctl == 1) {
                          my_notify_ctl = 0;
                          BleManager.getInstance().notify(
                              bleDevice,
                              characteristic.getService().getUuid().toString(),
                              characteristic.getUuid().toString(),
                              new BleNotifyCallback() {

                                  @Override
                                  public void onNotifySuccess() {
                                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void run() {
                                              addText(txt, "notify success");
                                          }
                                      });
                                  }

                                  @Override
                                  public void onNotifyFailure(final BleException exception) {
                                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void run() {
                                              addText(txt, exception.toString());
                                          }
                                      });
                                  }

                                  @Override
                                  public void onCharacteristicChanged(byte[] data) {
                                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void run() {
                                              addText(txt, HexUtil.formatHexString(characteristic.getValue(), true));
                                          }
                                      });
                                  }
                              });
                      } else {
                          BleManager.getInstance().stopNotify(
                              bleDevice,
                              characteristic.getService().getUuid().toString(),
                              characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                          my_notify_ctl = 1;
                      }
                      layout_add.addView(view_add);
                  }
                  break;
                  
          layout_container.addView(view);
      }
  }
```

Comment: hi. you forgot to ask a question, and this is a question and answer site. Especially, we don't even know which of the many many Arduino hardware types you're using, what your bluetooth interface is, and how you know you can't send more than 160B. Since we will not be able to locally reproduce on a short notice, it's also crucial that you explain what you did to figure out what exactly happens after 160B.

Comment: Edited the post with code, please check it.

Comment: thanks for all the detail, it really helps! So, what is the question you're asking?

Comment: What is your expected average transfer rate? Since BLE is much slower than classic Bluetooth, you may just overrun the channel. The datasheet specifies 1 kByte/s.